# Ubuntu crashes everytime I enter in the Internet

Tags: 14.04, networking

Installed Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop, I have a PC, that is not connected to the router through LAN and using wifi adapter tp tplink archer t2uh(this driver support my kernel). I started to put the driver assembled installed, even ping http://www.google.com correctly passed (although the packages passed until forced to stop ctrl + c).

But when I go to the Internet through Firefox or open the ubuntu center it crashed, just the screen crashed and once it's turned off and just a black screen with the commands. It helps reboot only. And then you need to create the modules again, load them all again and the story repeats (wrote the bash script) .

1) Why is this happening?

2) How can I load modules into startup? (or bash script)

Comment: Try putting everything in `/etc/rc.local`, which is run at boot(as root)

Comment: This advice is for auto startup, or it can help to solve crashing?

Comment: The advice is for auto startup only. It solves nothing.